# PDB symbol server on Linux

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols, pdb-files

How can I set up a symbol server for use with WinDbg and friends on a Linux machine that runs an HTTP server?

The upstream symbol servers [provided by Microsoft are HTTP servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) (e.g. `http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`) and I'd like to mimic their behavior and enable the usual Win32 debuggers to download the symbols from my own.

How can I achieve this without emulating bits and pieces of Windows (e.g. via Wine or KVM)?

Comment: Is it important that you can store symbol files on the symbol server using `symstore.exe` or would it be ok that your symbol server is capable of being accessed for download only?

Comment: @ThomasW.: download-only access is fine, `symstore.exe` functionality isn't required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the python [symstore](https://pypi.org/project/symstore/) package to publish PDB (and exe/dll) files to a local symstore directory, and then you just need serve that directory with a web server.

- configure a web-server to server contests of a directory, say /var/www/symbols
- install the 'symstore' python package

Each time you need to publish new PDB/exe/dll files, put them somewhere on you web-server. Then run 'symstore' command, provided by the python package, e.g.

symstore /var/www/symbols *pdb1 pdb2 ...*

This will copy all the specified files to correct subdirectories of /var/www/symbols and create a transaction entry in meta-files of the symbol store.

The symstore package also provides an python API, so it's possible to do the publication programmatically from any python process.

Symstore package installation instructions are here: https://pypi.org/project/symstore/

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't already, you might want to brush up on [how to create a symbol store on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/debug/using-symstore) because to create one on Linux you would need to create a compatible file structure.

First, it's important to note that sharing a symbol server over http is not special at all. Once a symbol store is created, it is just a matter of having it somewhere that is accessible via http. So, what is really important is the work that `symstore.exe` does.

I know you do not want to entertain the idea of using emulation, but you really have 2 choices:

1. Directly execute `symstore.exe` on a Linux box using something like Wine. (I don't know how well KVM would work here.)
2. Recreate the features of `symstore.exe` that you need to use.

Recreating `symstore.exe` can be pretty simple if you don't want to use any of its more advanced features like transactions, file links, or multiple users being able to import.

---

A simplified view of what `symstore.exe` does:

1. Creates a subdirectory in the output subdirectory with the name of each `pdb` imported.
2. Hashes the `pdb` file and creates a subfolder with the name of the hash.
3. Copies the `pdb` to the hash directory, optionally compressing it. (Or, depending on flags, stores a file `file.ptr` with the location the `pdb` is being imported from.)
4. Appends a line to `refs.ptr` in the hash directory with some information about the PDB that was imported. (I don't believe this file is actually used by the client, `dgbhelp.dll`, so this step could possibly be omitted.)
5. Updates files in the `[output directory]\000Admin` to support things like transactions. (Again, this is just here for future runs of `symstore.exe`.)
6. Touches `pingme.txt` in the output folder.

(More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-storage-format).)

This doesn't sound too complicated, but no doubt, it could take some time to get right. To start with, you might want to take a look at [Mozilla's build script](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/crashreporter/tools/symbolstore.py) which places `pdb`s in a structure that Windows debuggers know how to read. And some more information on it is available [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Breakpad/Design/Symbol_Server).

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've been using the Python [SymStore](https://pypi.org/project/symstore) library to create a symbol server on a Linux for a couple years now. I use this to update a [Python symbol server](https://github.com/SeanCline/PythonSymbols) periodically using Travis CI.

Answer (score 2):

Update: see a [more detailed answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323175/480982).

---

Given the assumption that you are the administrator of all symbols, you can do like this:

1. Create the "master" symbol store on your machine using `symstore.exe`.
2. Create a new virtual host or use an existing domain and create a subdirectory for storing your symbols.
3. Upload the complete master symbol store to the directory

To add new symbols, execute `symstore.exe` on your Windows machine again. Then upload all files again. You can skip the ones which already exist on the server, except `pingme.txt`. Existing files should not change, otherwise their hash should be different as well, which means they are in a different subdirectory.

You might want to protect your symbols from access. WinDbg supports `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`, at least with basic authentication. I guess you're familiar with that.

Comment: Interesting idea. So the files contain relative paths?

Comment: Which files contain relative paths? I am simply using Filezilla, upload my files from `c:\productsymbols` including all subfolders to `ftp://symbols.example.com/` and symbols.example.com is also accessible via HTTP.