# VS IDE and WinDbg says that it cannot find symbol file

Tags: debugging, windbg, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

So, I primarily use VS IDE for debugging.  I got a dump file and tried to do a postmortem on it.  All of the DLLs loaded their respective PDBs except one and I don't know exactly why.  This information would be helpful in determining if the dump file got corrupted in some way or if the client has a corrupted DLL.

I have also tried to use WinDbg to debug this, which I have some but not a lot of experience with.  I updated the symbol paths to the directory that has the PDBs of the proper build and some others that it also might match up with as well.  I loaded up the dump file and that same DLL is not having a matching PDB file found.

So the question is, what prevents a particular PDB not match with a dump file and how can I find out what that information is?

Comment: Debug > Windows > Modules, right-click the DLL and select Symbol Load Information.

Comment: @LexLi, which one what?

Comment: " All of the DLLs loaded their respective PDBs except one", then which one?

Comment: @LexLi, the one that is part of our application that is part of the code that we have source for?  I'm confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: @HansPassant, The symbol load info is saying _Skipped checking location. The symbol file was not found in this location before._ which isn't that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols have a hash and a timestamp. Both need to match in order to load the symbols. In WinDbg, there's an option to force loading symbols that don't match (`.symopt+ 0x40`). Visual Studio doesn't have such an option, so you need to use [chkmatch](http://debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) to make symbols match. Note that this is a dangerous operation, because it modifies the PDB file. You should create a backup copy and delete the modified file after you're done.

If you can't figure out what executable exactly is in the dump file, try `.writemem <FileName> <Range>` with the starting address of the executable and its size. See also [How to retrieve assembly from a raw memory dump?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8962/3355).

For checking a dump file for corruption, I only know about [DumpChk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dumpchk), which comes with WinDbg. AFAIK, the file format does not allow detection of single byte corruptions or similar.

> I updated the symbol paths to the directory that has the PDBs

You should [set up a symbol server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323175/480982). With a symbol server, there's no need to look for symbols or configure directories.

Comment: Yeah, I already saw chkmatch and I can't use it.  It doesn't work for dump files, only executables.  My company has not setup a symbol server atm, and unless there is a great benefit, we are unlikely to do so.  How would I know what failed to match?  You've only answered half the question.

Comment: `dumpchk.exe` didn't find anything wrong with the dump file.  However, the PDB that I have should be the matching ones to the dump file.  We version our SW and make sure that the historical DLLs and PDBs and other files are stored in a safe location.  Not sure what's going on. :(

Comment: Did you try `.writemem` for the DLL and compare the result to the DLL you have?