# What do the various convertstore errors mean?

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols

I am trying to convert a 2 tier symbol store into a 3-tier symbol store using the `convertstore.exe` tool as [described by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-store-folder-tree).

However, I get error messages which do not tell me much. Depending on which store I want to convert I get the following errors:

- `Failed initial checks.`
- `Failed to lock Symbol Store. Error 0x00000003.`
- `ERROR: Couldn't create X:\...\index2.txt. Error 0x00000005.`

Sometimes `convertstore` seems to run without error message, but it hasn't converted the store.

What do these error messages mean and how to mitigate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Failed initial checks.

Possible causes:

1. This error can happen if you run `convertstore` without any arguments.

   Mitigation: Use the correct syntax `convertstore.exe -s <store>`
2. The symbol store is already a 3-tier store

   Mitigation: none, if the symbol store is already a 3-tier store. The tool will only convert in one direction. It cannot convert back and forth.

   Mitigation: If it isn't a 3-tier store, delete the file `index2.txt`.

#### Failed to lock Symbol Store. Error 0x00000003.

Possible causes:

1. The symbol store does not have a `pingme.txt` or `000Admin` folder.

   Mitigation: specify a symbol store, not an arbitrary folder that happens to contain some symbols.

   Mitigation: create a zero byte file `pingme.txt` and an empty folder `000Admin`.

#### Failed to move <pdb> > <pdb>. Error 0x00000005.

Possible causes:

1. The file is currently in use.

   Mitigation: close other programs that may currently access the file, then delete `index2.txt` and run the command again.
2. You don't have write access to the symbol store.

   Mitigation: use SysInternals Process Monitor to diagnose the issue. Note that `convertstore` will not use the drive letters of mapped network shares, but use the SMB share name instead.

#### Couldn't create index2.txt. Error 0x00000005.

Possible causes:

1. You don't have write access to the symbol store.

   Mitigation: use SysInternals Process Monitor to diagnose the issue. Note that `convertstore` will not use the drive letters of mapped network shares, but use the SMB share name instead.

#### Failed to move <pdb> > <pdb>. Error 0x000000B7.

Possible causes:

1. The destination file already exists in the 3-tier part of the store. Someone worked on the symbol store in the meanwhile and downloaded new symbols, storing them in the 2-tier format. You now have them in two locations: a 2-tier folder and a 3-tier folder.

   Mitigation: delete the 2-tier version manually.

#### No error message

Possible causes:

1. `convertstore` x64 version 10.0.22000.1 suffers from an access violation at `convertstore!ConvertAdminFileW+0x1c9`

   Mitigation: submit the crash dump to Microsoft and hope that they will fix this. Then run the x86 (32 bit) version.